# Trying to get a value from 5 different tables based on another value

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to get the `date` value from 5 different tables based on the `usertype` value and display it on `DATATABLES table`.

**For example** :- if `usertype` value is 2 than I want to get the `date` value from table `table_two`.

Here is what I have got so far :

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN tm.usertype = 1 THEN type_1.date 
WHEN tm.usertype = 2 THEN type_2.date 
WHEN tm.usertype = 3 THEN type_3.date 
WHEN tm.usertype = 4 THEN type_4.date 
WHEN tm.usertype = 5 THEN type_5.date 
END, 
tm.id,
tm.usertype
FROM table_main tm 
LEFT JOIN table_one type_1 ON tm.id=type_1.uid 
LEFT JOIN table_two type_2 ON tm.id=type_2.uid 
LEFT JOIN table_three type_3 ON tm.id=type_3.uid 
LEFT JOIN table_four type_4 ON tm.id=type_4.uid 
LEFT JOIN table_five type_5 ON tm.id=type_5.uid
```

The error I'm getting from DATATABLES is:-

> DataTables warning: table id=example - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Comment: make sure the column exists in every table. `date` is also a column name you should avoid since it can be a reserved word.

Comment: this column exist in all tables

Comment: Still not working, I have tried a different column and the same issue

Comment: Date is a reserved keyword. If db is Oracle then enclose the reserved word in double quotes as: `THEN type_1."date "`

Comment: For MSSQL Server, date is a reserved word, so you'll need to wrap it: `type_1.[date]`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is clearly caused by a column not having the name you expect.  However, your query may still not return what you want, because id values *could* (at least in theory) be shared among tables.

It is better to move the conditional logic to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT COALESCE(type_1.date, type_2.date, type_3.date, type_4.date, type_5.date) 
       tm.id, tm.usertype
FROM table_main tm LEFT JOIN
     table_one type_1
     ON tm.id = type_1.uid AND tm.usertype = 1 LEFT JOIN
     table_two type_2
     ON tm.id = type_2.uid AND tm.usertype = 2 LEFT JOIN
     table_three type_3
     ON tm.id = type_3.uid AND tm.usertype = 3 LEFT JOIN
     table_four type_4
     ON tm.id = type_4.uid AND tm.usertype = 4 LEFT JOIN
     table_five type_5
     ON tm.id = type_5.uid AND tm.usertype = 5 ;
```

This won't fix the specific error you have.  For that, you need to fix the column names.